# merge 2 mysql queries into one with JOIN+OR statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Code is self-explanatory

How can i merge these 2 SQL queries into one ?

something like "JOIN..ON.. OR shop_tags.parent_tag_id = shop_tags_link.tag_id"

```
// query PARENT tags with this Design ID
$list_tags_link_query = "SELECT * FROM shop_tags_link JOIN shop_tags ON shop_tags_link.tag_id = shop_tags.tag_id WHERE shop_tags_link.design = '$design'";
$list_tags_link_exec = mysql_query($list_tags_link_query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($list_tags_link_exec)) {
    $tag_id = $row["tag_id"];
    $tag_fr = utf8_decode($row["tag_fr"]);
    $tag_en = utf8_decode($row["tag_en"]);
    echo "[<a href=\"$canon/?delete=$tag_id\">x</a>] $tag_fr ($tag_en), ";
        // query CHILD tags with the corresponding PARENT's tag_id
        $list_tags_child_query = "SELECT * FROM shop_tags WHERE parent_tag_id = '$tag_id'";
        $list_tags_child_exec = mysql_query($list_tags_child_query) or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($list_tags_child_exec)) {
            $tag_fr = utf8_decode($row["tag_fr"]);
            $tag_en = utf8_decode($row["tag_en"]);
            $tag_id = $row["tag_id"];
            echo "<font size=\"1\">[<a href=\"$canon/?delete=$tag_id\">x</a>] $tag_fr ($tag_en), </font>";
        }
    }
```

I want only 1 query instead of 2

Comment: Would a Union do this? (ie. Select * From Foo Union Select * From Foo)

Comment: Never used Union statement before. Could you please post an example for my case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do with one query only then you may try below solution.But if your database tables contains more records then this query takes more time for execution.

```
$list_tags_link_query = "SELECT stl.*,st.*,(select GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('@@',in_t.tag_id,if(in_t.tag_fr <> '',in_t.tag_fr,''),if(in_t.tag_en <> '',in_t.tag_en,''))  SEPARATOR '|||') from shop_tags as in_t where in_t.parent_tag_id = stl.tag_id) as childs_details FROM shop_tags_link stl JOIN shop_tags st ON stl.tag_id = st.tag_id WHERE stl.design = '$design'";
$list_tags_link_exec = mysql_query($list_tags_link_query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($list_tags_link_exec)) {
    $tag_id = $row["tag_id"];
    $tag_fr = utf8_decode($row["tag_fr"]);
    $tag_en = utf8_decode($row["tag_en"]);
    echo "[<a href=\"$canon/?delete=$tag_id\">x</a>] $tag_fr ($tag_en), ";

    $childs_details=$row["childs_details"];
    if($childs_details!=""){
        $child_row=explode("|||",$childs_details);
        if(is_array($child_row) && count($child_row)>0){
            for($i=0;$i<count($child_row);$i++){
                $child_row_detail=explode("@@",$child_row[$i]);

                $tag_id = $child_row_detail[0];
                $tag_fr = utf8_decode($child_row_detail[1]);
                $tag_en = utf8_decode($child_row_detail[2]);
                echo "<font size=\"1\">[<a href=\"$canon/?delete=$tag_id\">x</a>] $tag_fr ($tag_en), </font>";
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you almost proper code but you have made one mistake in it.**$row** is overwritten in loop so just correct it.Please check below code.

```
// query PARENT tags with this Design ID
$list_tags_link_query = "SELECT * FROM shop_tags_link JOIN shop_tags ON shop_tags_link.tag_id = shop_tags.tag_id WHERE shop_tags_link.design = '$design'";
$list_tags_link_exec = mysql_query($list_tags_link_query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($list_tags_link_exec)) {
    $tag_id = $row["tag_id"];
    $tag_fr = utf8_decode($row["tag_fr"]);
    $tag_en = utf8_decode($row["tag_en"]);
    echo "[<a href=\"$canon/?delete=$tag_id\">x</a>] $tag_fr ($tag_en), ";
        // query CHILD tags with the corresponding PARENT's tag_id
        $list_tags_child_query = "SELECT * FROM shop_tags WHERE parent_tag_id = '$tag_id'";
        $list_tags_child_exec = mysql_query($list_tags_child_query) or die(mysql_error());
        while($child_row = mysql_fetch_array($list_tags_child_exec)) {
            $tag_fr = utf8_decode($child_row["tag_fr"]);
            $tag_en = utf8_decode($child_row["tag_en"]);
            $tag_id = $child_row["tag_id"];
            echo "<font size=\"1\">[<a href=\"$canon/?delete=$tag_id\">x</a>] $tag_fr ($tag_en), </font>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: but... it's still doing 2 queries and i want only 1 :(

Comment: Dear Jo Libertire , Yes we can do with one query but if your data base tables contains large amount of data than it may slower the db performance.I have added a new solution for this, you please check it once.